# Const function in STL containers

Tags: c++, stl, constants

I have a problem using the STL containers in c++

function 1;

```
void addStudent(const Student &s){                       
    set<GradeColumn>::iterator itr;

    for(itr = gradeColumns.begin(); itr != gradeColumns.end(); itr++){
        itr->addStudent(s, DID_NOT_COMPLETE);
    }
}
```

function 2:

```
void addStudent(const Student &s,  int grade) const {
    column.insert(pair<Student, int>(s, grade));
}
```

Okay, so in function 1 I use addStudent, but the compiler gives me an error unless I declare addStudent as a const function (the error is "The object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function").

But if I do declare addStudent as a const function, then column.insert(...) gives me thee next error: "No instance of overloaded function matches the argument list and object 9the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)".

Is there any way to fix that? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us relevant code: `operator<` or `std::less<GradeColumn>`. Can `addStudent` change `GradeColumn` order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the class you are trying to modify is also the *key* in the set. And this is required to be *immutable*. i.e. it is not correct behaviour to change the key once the item is in the set.

You need to consider a different structure, I would advice that you extract the *key* element out into a separate key structure and use a map to map the key to the mutable data content of your structure.

Comment: I would advise that you do not change your whole design just because of a design error in `std::std`. It is common to have the key packed inside a record (database line) and safe as long as you know what you are doing. With multiple keys it is not even possible to keep the key out in general.

Comment: @curiousguy, well, it's easier to get it wrong than to get it right, and at the start, it's better to *work* with the standard than to hack around it.

Comment: "_it's better to work with the standard_" Working with `std::set` safe-for-babies design means either sticking to very simple uses, or hacking around the C++ language (notably dropping const-correctness) or hacking around the `std::set<>::value_type` constness. Working "against" `std::set` is easier and cleaner. What we really need is access to the sane `rbtree` interface hidden behind the "safe" sugar-coated set/map/multiset/multimap interfaces.

Comment: @curiousguy, not everyone is at the same level as you, and nor do they have the same requirements. The standard libraries are designed for the general case, and for the general case, they are hard to beat. I'm not convinced your strategy will work for beginners, and I would caution against recommending it. If it would work, all known C++ literature would take that approach - they don't, it's for a reason.

Comment: "_not everyone is at the same level as you_" Yes, and no everyone knows how to properly deal with the castrated `std::set` interface. "_The standard libraries are designed for the general case, and for the general case, they are hard to beat._" For the general case, you need the internal `rbtree` interface. Only in quite simple cases can you use the set/map interface in a natural and easy way. "_I'm not convinced your strategy will work for beginners_" Which strategy? The one I am suggesting in my answer?

Comment: "_and I would caution against recommending it._" Why would you? I would caution beginners against twisting their design to deal with `std::set`. "_If it would work,_" and you know that it doesn't work how? "_all known C++ literature would take that approach - they don't, it's for a reason._" Which reason?

Comment: @curiousguy, No you *don't need* that interface, you keep going on about it - but it's still not clear why you *need* it. I would guess that 99% of the cases are indeed quite simple - you've evidently got a few cases in the other 1%. By *strategy* I'm refering to using the `rbtree` interface - I make no reference to your answer. All I'm suggesting is that the OP look at his design, and which type of container may be better suitable for what he is trying to do - if you can't see that - then I can't be bothered wasting any more time with your ranting.

Answer (score 2):

The keys of a `std::set` are always constant. This is a requirement of the container, since the elements are ordered by key value, and if keys were mutable, the container couldn't guarantee that its invariants are maintained.

If your relational operator on `GradeColumn` is independent of the things you need to access in your `insert()` member function, then you can declare those member objects `mutable` so that you can modify them even when the key object itself is constant.

Comment: How do I declare them mutable so that will work? I've tried every option that I could think of.

Comment: "_This is a requirement of the container_" No, it is a (bad) design choice. "_the container couldn't guarantee that its invariants are maintained._" Actually it can't. It's the responsibility of the user.

Comment: curiousguy, I believe you're mistaken.  Those are requirements of set, from the C++ standard.  @KerrekSB: instead of recommending mutable, maybe you should recommend a different container instead?  I lived to regret every time I typed mutable.

Comment: @GMan: Why don't you post your class definition, and we can take a look.

Comment: @MooingDuck "_curiousguy, I believe you're mistaken. Those are requirements of set, from the C++ standard._" As I said, that the elements are const is the result of a bad design choice for the interface of `std::set`. And the standard requirement for a container was that the elements are assignable, so the first C++ standard actually required the element for all containers to be non-const (and for `std::set` to be const). So associative containers were not even implementable in C++ "98".

Comment: @GMan You would have to change the definition of `GradeColumn`, and give away const-correctness.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your answer to my comment. If your answer is:

## "*yes, `addStudent` can change `GradeColumn` order*"

The answer is: **Associative containers design saved you** as explained in other answers.

## "*no, `addStudent` cannot change `GradeColumn` order*"

The answer is: **Associative containers design strikes again.**

The fix is (sketch):

```
class GradeColumnElement {
    mutable GradeColumn col;

    friend bool operator<(const GradeColumnElement& left, const GradeColumnElement& right) {
        return left.col < right.col;
    }

public:
    GradeColumnElement (const GradeColumn& col) : col(col) {
    }

    // const interface: 
    // modifications of GradeColumn that do NOT affect ordering
    void addStudent(const Student &s, int grade) const {
        col.addStudent (s, grade);
    }
};
```

then you use `set<GradeColumnElement>` instead of `set<GradeColumn>`.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks a lot, and the answer is that addStudent can't change GradeColumn.

I'll have to understand what exactly you did here, but I believe this will work. Thanks! Will report back tomorrow.